# Where to create common functionalities with view in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, components

I am new in cakephp. I have a module with name contact us in 1 of my project. This module need to show on almost all pages of the website. So my question is, for this common module can we create component or there is some other way to complete it? I read about the components for the site and found that components does not have own views. Please suggest me how can we do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Cakephp Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)**

Many applications have small blocks of presentation code that need to be repeated from page to page, sometimes in different places in the layout. CakePHP can help you repeat parts of your website that need to be reused. These reusable parts are called Elements. Ads, help boxes, navigational controls, extra menus, login forms, and callouts are often implemented in CakePHP as elements. An element is basically a mini-view that can be included in other views, in layouts, and even within other elements. Elements can be used to make a view more readable, placing the rendering of repeating elements in its own file. They can also help you re-use content fragments in your application.

Elements live in the /app/View/Elements/ folder, and have the .ctp filename extension. They are output using the element method of the view:

```
echo $this->element('helpbox');
```

For more details check out  [Views — CakePHP Cookbook 2.x documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements)